# How to generate all web server errors programaticallly

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, httpwebrequest

I want to generate the all errors of particular link if link is not working then it should be shown particular web server error.

Here is my code. Please suggest where should program should done I can get all errors if link is not working

```
  public partial class WebForm2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          

        }
        protected void btnRender_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string strResult = string.Empty;

            WebResponse objResponse;
            WebRequest objRequest = System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(urltxt.Text);

            objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();

            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                strResult = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
            strResult = strResult.Replace("<form id='form1' method='post' action=''>", "");
            strResult = strResult.Replace("</form>", "");
            //strResult = strResult.Replace("<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" /><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">");
            div.InnerHtml = strResult;

        }

        protected void btn_createlink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var links = TextBox1.Text.Split(new string[] { "\n", "\r" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            foreach (var link in links)
            {
                if (!IsLinkWorking(link))
                {
                    //Here you can show the error. You don't specify how you want to show it.
                    TextBox2.Text += string.Format("{0}\nNot working\n\n ", link);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox2.Text += string.Format("{0}\n working\n\n", link);
                }
            }
        }


bool IsLinkWorking(string url)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

    //You can set some parameters in the "request" object...
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, cert, chain, ssl) => true;

    try
    {
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        return true;
    }
    catch
    { 
        //TODO: Check for the right exception here
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add information on what problems you have with the code.

Comment: i want to generate error code like 401 error instead of this                    if (!IsLinkWorking(link))
                {
                    
                    TextBox2.Text += string.Format("{0}\nNot working\n\n ", link);
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox2.Text += string.Format("{0}\n working\n\n", link);
                }
            }

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i need to print particular error instead not working printing

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov hey bro you had given answer below..i accept it but i have already send the web request so please what i have to write insted of working or not just edit mycode..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer on "how to use Visual Studio and MSDN to find help on methods and related exceptions":

- in Visual Studio select method you need information on and press F1. Help on given method will be shown. Alternatively you can search on your favorite search engine (i.e. http://bing.com) for class+method name - i.e. http://www.bing.com/search?q=HttpWebResponse.GetResponse .
- MSDN page on given method will either come up from help or usually will be one of the first result in search result - read it.
- Most methods contain "Exceptions" section listing exceptions and often "Remarks" section covering details. 
  In your case [HttpWebResponse.GetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) shows that it throws `WebException` exception and Remarks section goes into details of the exception. In particular it mentions [WebException.Response](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response.aspx) property that covers exactly what you are looking for (including sample code).

Partial sample from the article showing usage of `Status` and `Response.StatusCode`

```
try 
{
  var myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(pathThatReturns404);
  var myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
}
catch(WebException e) 
{
    if(e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}",
            ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
    }
}
```